# Why does the orientation of a linearlayout determine the centering of a child element?

Tags: android, android-layout

Why doesn't this center a button both horizontally and vertically on the screen?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="click"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

layout_gravity specifies alignment for the button within it's parent.  But this only centers the button vertically, not horizontally. If I change the orientation of the linearlayout to vertical, the button is centered horizontally, not vertically.  I don't see why the orientation matters here because I only have 1 child element.

I know I can achieve this by specifying the gravity in the LinearLayout with android:gravity="true" or using a RelativeLayout and have the Button android:centerInParent="true", but I'd like to know how android came up with the layout in the code above.

P.S.  Why does the background color still show as gray if that's the hex code for white?

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout will only allocate the *minimum* amount of space needed for a view in the direction of its orientation.  That's why you can't seem to center a view in the same direction as the orientation. LinearLayout generally assumes that you want to put multiple things adjacent to each other, not occupy an entire space unconditionally for a single item.

P.S. I see the entire background of the LinearLayout as white in my preview view in Android Studio, so I don't know what you mean in your P.S.

Comment: the preview view shows white, running it on my galaxy shows gray

Comment: can you post your reference for "allocate the minimum amount of space needed for a view in the direction of it's orientation"?  It's not here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: I'm speaking from the experience of having created hundreds of LinearLayouts in the past.  It's just the expectation that people have when stacking items with this tool.  If you have a single item, that's not part of the problem that LinearLayout is trying to solve.  FrameLayout may be a better choice for positioning a single child.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a linear layout to display items in the middle of the screen, as these are meant to list items in a row. Use a relative layout instead. So your code should look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:background="#FFFFFF">

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="click"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```